swiftui stream text response from http request forbid user scroll screen
i'm writing a ai chat app, when handling stream response from http request, i find i can't scroll the screen util the response are all received.
my code below:
my view: scrollview, list for show message, textfield for user to input
ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
    List {
        ForEach(messages) { message in
            MessageView(
                message: message,
                input: $inputMessage
            )
                .id(message.msgid)
        }
         Spacer()
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .id("end_text")
    }.id(UUID())
    TextField("write something here...", text: $inputMessage)
        .submitLabel(.send)
        .onSubmit {
            scrollView.scrollTo("end_text", anchor:.center)
            sendMessage()
        }             
}

struct MessageView: View {
    let message: Message
    @Binding var input: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if message.type == 1 {
                Spacer()
            } else {
                Image("ai")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            }
            VStack(alignment: message.type == 1 ? .trailing : .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Text(message.text)
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct Message: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable, Encodable, Decodable {
    public var id = UUID()
    public var msgid: String = UUID().uuidString
    public var text: String
    public var type: Int  // 0: chat, 1: user, 2:system
}                     

the sendMessage function: send stream request and append chunk response to view

func sendMessage() {
        inputMessage = inputMessage.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if( (inputMessage.count<=0) || (inputMessage.count > maxLength)  ) {
            return
        }
        if(waitForResponse) {
            return
        }
        waitForResponse = true
        let message = Message(text: inputMessage, type: 1)
        messages.append(message)
        let sendMsg = inputMessage
    
        UIKit.Task {
            do {
                    let stream = try await chatClient.sendStreamMessage(text: sendMsg)
                    var messageResp = Message(text: "", type: 0)
                    messages.append(messageResp)
                    for try await chunk in stream {
                        messageResp.text += chunk.content
                        messages[messages.count - 1] = messageResp
                    }
                    waitForResponse = false
            } catch {
                waitForResponse = false
                let qa_answer = "error"
                let message = Message(text: qa_answer, type: 0)
                messages.append(message)
            }
        }
        inputMessage = ""
    }
    

http request function: send stream http request
func sendStreamMessage(text: String) async throws -> AsyncThrowingStream<StreamChunk, Error> {
    let url = URL(string: "http://")!
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    headers.forEach { urlRequest.setValue($1, forHTTPHeaderField: $0) }
    
    let request = Request(
        content: text
    )
    urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(request)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    
    session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
    session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
    
    let (result, response) = try await session.bytes(for: urlRequest)
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        throw "Invalid response"
    }
    guard 200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
        var errorText = ""
        for try await line in result.lines {
            errorText += line
        }
        if let data = errorText.data(using: .utf8), let errorResponse = try? jsonDecoder.decode(ErrorRootResponse.self, from: data).error {
            errorText = "\n\(errorResponse.message)"
        }
        throw "Bad Response: \(httpResponse.statusCode). \(errorText)"
    }
    return AsyncThrowingStream<StreamChunk, Error> {  continuation in
        UIKit.Task(priority: .userInitiated) { [weak self] in
            do {
                for try await line in result.lines {
                    if line.hasPrefix("data: ") {
                        let jsonString = String(line.dropFirst(6))
                        if let chunkData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
                            let chunk = try JSONDecoder().decode(StreamChunk.self, from: chunkData)
                            continuation.yield(chunk)
                        }
                    }
                }
                continuation.finish()
            } catch {
                continuation.finish(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StreamChunk: Decodable {
    let content: String
}
struct Request: Codable {
    let content: String
}

struct ErrorRootResponse: Decodable {
    let error: ErrorResponse
}
struct ErrorResponse: Decodable {
    let message: String
    let type: String?
}

i want when the response is generating, user can still scoll the screen
i asked chatgpt for help but still not working
